# getting an error of BUILD_FAIL

Tags: c++, netbeans

I am using netbeans IDE on ubuntu for c++ and whenever i am running a program i am getting an error of BUILD_FAIL

```
    "/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
    make[1]: Entering directory `/home/rupesh/NetBeansProjects/Cpp1'
    "/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/cpp1
    make[2]: Entering directory `/home/rupesh/NetBeansProjects/Cpp1'
    mkdir -p dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86
    g++-o dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/cpp1 build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o build/Debug/GNU-         Linux-x86/1.o  
   build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/1.o: In function `main':
   /home/rupesh/NetBeansProjects/Cpp1/1.cpp:4: multiple definition of `main'
   build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o:/home/rupesh/NetBeansProjects/Cpp1/main.cpp:15: first   defined here
  collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
  make[2]: *** [dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/cpp1] Error 1
  make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/rupesh/NetBeansProjects/Cpp1'
  make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
  make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/rupesh/NetBeansProjects/Cpp1'
  make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2
```

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 190ms)

I am running a simple program to print hello world.

Comment: `multiple definition of main` ... you have an error in your source code.

Comment: as a little side-note, i'd hope you're using `int main` as opposed to `main`

Comment: can you show us, your code snippet.

Comment: #include<iostream>
     using namespace std;
     int main()
      {
       cout<<"hello world" ;
       return 0;
      }
This is the code and i comiled and ran it through the termial but don't know why the netbeans is creating the problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what the compiler is spitting out, it seems you have two files that specify a `main()` being built as one project.

> /home/rupesh/NetBeansProjects/Cpp1/**1.cpp:4:** multiple definition of
>   `main'
>
> build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o:/home/rupesh/NetBeansProjects/Cpp1/**main.cpp:15**:
>
> first   defined here collect2: ld returned 1 exit status make[2]: ***
>
> [dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/cpp1] Error 1

check your folders to make sure you have no other files that the compiler is attempting to build in with main.cpp, in this case look for a `1.cpp`